# Upgrade spring boot 2.7.4 to latest available Spring Boot 2.7.x version

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a project that is stuck at version 2.7.4 and I need to update it to the latest 2.7.x.

All I have to do is update the pom.xml?

Comment: Probably, depends if used the parent managed versions or overwrote the dependency versions. 2.7.4 is not that band, I have something on 2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: The most recent version of spring boot 2.7. is 2.7.10 (2.7.11 will be release tomorrow. https://calendar.spring.io/) ...